# Getting mplayer to return an error when it cannot load a radio station

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mplayer

I am using mplayer to create an internet radio alarm clock with a raspberry pi. The setup works when given a working url, but will exit 'successfully', i.e. without an error code, when given a broken one. I need this clock to definitely play to wake me up, hence if one url does not work I want it to return an error code so that the bash script can try the next one and so on until one does. This is the output for a non-functional url "https://fake.com".

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mplayer https://fake.com || echo "failed"
MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
Cannot open file '/home/pi/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /home/pi/.mplayer/input.conf.
Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.
Playing https://fake.com.
No stream found to handle url https://fake.com
Exiting... (End of file)
```

It does not echo the command failed. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Probably a bug or a feature of your mplayer2. You could try the original mplayer  from http://www.mplayerhq.hu